# webpack2 doesn't load chunk from the correct path

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have a simple setup:

```
|-- a.js
| --b.js
```

**a.js**

```
import('./b.js').then(function (m) {
    console.log('imported');
});
```

**b.js**

```
export function b() {}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './a.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: '/dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
```

After the build, two chunks are created in the `/dist` folder:

```
|---0.bundle.js
|---bundle.js
```

I load `bundle.js` on the client side, and webpack requests `0.bundle.js`, however, it's using incorrect path:

```
http://localhost:63342/0.bundle.js
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:63342/dist/0.bundle.js
```

Why so?

I've also tried to use `output.publicPath`, but it still tries to load without `/dist`.

Comment: Having the same issues now.

Comment: @wintercounter, not sure if I found solution back then

Comment: I've did find, I'm applying it in runtime using `__webpack_public_path__`

Comment: @wintercounter, you can post it as an answer